# How to properly create a secure web server with Dart?

Tags: dart, ssl, ssl-certificate, dart-shelf, dart-server

This a typical code provided by Dart for a server using `Shelf` package :

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:shelf/shelf.dart';
import 'package:shelf/shelf_io.dart';
import 'package:shelf_router/shelf_router.dart';

// Configure routes.
final _router = Router()
  ..get('/', _rootHandler)
  ..get('/echo/<message>', _echoHandler);

Response _rootHandler(Request req) {
  return Response.ok('Hello, World!\n');
}

Response _echoHandler(Request request) {
  final message = request.params['message'];
  return Response.ok('$message\n');
}

void main(List<String> args) async {
  // Use any available host or container IP (usually `0.0.0.0`).
  final ip = InternetAddress.anyIPv4;

  // Configure a pipeline that logs requests.
  final _handler = Pipeline().addMiddleware(logRequests()).addHandler(_router);

  // For running in containers, we respect the PORT environment variable.
  final port = int.parse(Platform.environment['PORT'] ?? '8080');
  final server = await serve(_handler, ip, port);
  print('Server listening on port ${server.port}');
}
```

What/How should it need to be modified to support secure connections (HTTPS) **only**?

I don't really understand about certificates, so if you could give a detail explanation about how to generate/buy them and how to link them to server or any reference for dummies it'd be great.

**P.S.**: My host is a Linux distro (Manjaro) running the following Docker containers: a file server (Dart with Shelf) and GraphQL server (Postgraphile). Do I need to make configurations for every service running in my host?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, my thanks to @KevinMoore for his answer, but it is not complete as I wished, so this is my answer:

According to [Dart help](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.14.4/dart-io/HttpServer-class.html) the above code is modified like this:

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:shelf/shelf.dart';
import 'package:shelf/shelf_io.dart';
import 'package:shelf_router/shelf_router.dart';

// Configure routes.
final _router = Router()
  ..get('/', _rootHandler)
  ..get('/echo/<message>', _echoHandler);

Response _rootHandler(Request req) {
  return Response.ok('Hello, World!\n');
}

Response _echoHandler(Request request) {
  final message = request.params['message'];
  return Response.ok('$message\n');
}

SecurityContext getSecurityContext() { // Bind with a secure HTTPS connection
  final chain = Platform.script.resolve('certificates/server_chain.pem').toFilePath();
  final key = Platform.script.resolve('certificates/server_key.pem').toFilePath();
  
  return SecurityContext()
  ..useCertificateChain(chain)
  ..usePrivateKey(key, password: 'dartdart');
}

void main(List<String> args) async {
  // Use any available host or container IP (usually `0.0.0.0`).
  final ip = InternetAddress.anyIPv4;

  // Configure a pipeline that logs requests.
  final _handler = Pipeline().addMiddleware(logRequests()).addHandler(_router);

  // For running in containers, we respect the PORT environment variable.
  final port = int.parse(Platform.environment['PORT'] ?? '443');
  final server = await serve(_handler, ip, port, securityContext: getSecurityContext());
  print('Server listening on port ${server.port}');
}
```

For that code I'm using certificates and password provided by Dart Team in [its repository](https://github.com/dart-lang/dart-tutorials-samples/tree/master/httpserver/bin) for educational purposes only.

If you need certificates for your server in production, you can get them for free with [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/getting-started/).

These videos can be useful about how to get and use these certificates:

- [Contratar un certificado SSL GRATIS con Let's Encrypt | DevOps Automation](https://youtu.be/rfo_7J_0MGw)
- [Let's Encrypt Explained: Free SSL](https://youtu.be/jrR_WfgmWEw)

[This tutorial](https://www.cresc.co.jp/tech/java/Google_Dart2/servers/https_server/https_server.html) (in Japanese) also is a good reference.

Answer (score 2):

Have you seen https://api.dart.dev/dev/2.16.0-7.0.dev/dart-io/HttpServer-class.html ?

You can pass an `HttpServer` instance to `serveRequests` (https://pub.dev/documentation/shelf/latest/shelf_io/serveRequests.html) in pkg:shelf